# Hide bootstrap alert if empty don´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide my bootstrap alert if it is empty. It hide correctly when page load, problem is when I do a push who insert data into div, it don´t show alert and it keep with `display = none`

[image]

**HTML**

```
 <div id="a1" class="alert alert-success">
                <div id="discussion"></div>
            </div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    hideAlert("a1");

    function hideAlert(id) {
        var text = $('#' + id + '#discussion').text();
        console.log(text.length);
        if (text.length <= 0)
            $('#' + id).hide();
    }
</script>
```

**Edit**

I try it using `input event` , it occurs same. It hide but it don't show when get value

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#discussion').keyup(function () {

        // If value is not empty
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            // Hide the element
            $('#a1').hide();
        } else {
            // Otherwise show it
            $('#a1').show();
        }
    }).keyup();


</script>
```

Comment: Where is the code that shows the alert? Or do you refresh the page?

Comment: Alert dont showed up thats my problem, when I do a post  `<div id="discussion"></div>` get value as image  but alert dont appears @DarrenSweeney

Comment: You need to remove the display:none class from alert when there is text inside.

Comment: @hunzaboy: Well, yeah, that's exactly what they said they're trying to do. Why are you repeating the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector must be `#a1 #discussion` no `#a1#discussion`.So:

**Change :**

```
$('#' + id + '#discussion')
```

**To:**

```
$('#' + id + ' #discussion')
              ^-----------------
```

```js
hideAlert("a1");
function hideAlert(id) {
    var text = $('#' + id + ' #discussion').text();
    console.log(text.length);
    if (text.length <= 0)
        $('#' + id).hide();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1" class="alert alert-success">
    <div id="discussion"></div>
</div>
```

**After Update your question:**

```js
setInterval(function(){ hideAlert("a1"); }, 3000);

function hideAlert(id) {
    var text = $('#' + id + ' #discussion').text();
    if (text.length <= 0)
    $('#' + id).hide();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1" class="alert alert-success">
    <div id="discussion" contenteditable="true">Some Text...</div>
</div>
```

**Note : Remove text in `div` and see result**

Comment: I have one problem, it still hide correctly, problem is I dont refresh page when discussion get value, what I need to do to div always listening?

Comment: @Ledwing , how `div` get value? if `div` is editable and you type value in it, use of `input` event.

Comment: It get value from push notification, so I dont need to reload page or do anything to get value there. what you mean about input event?

Answer (score 4):

Why not try using the :empty css pseudo-class like this:

## CSS

```
#discussion{
    display: block;
}     
#discussion:empty{
    display: none;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="discussion" class="alert alert-success"></div>
```

**Note**: The beginning and closing tags should be next to each other for the pseudo-class to work (like the beginning and closing div tags next to each other without any line breaks or space in the html shown above).